# Is there a better way to test the following methods without mocks returning mocks?

Tags: java, tdd, mocking, mockito

Assume the following setup:

```
interface Entity {}

interface Context { 
     Result add(Entity entity);
}

interface Result {
     Context newContext();
     SpecificResult specificResult();
}

class Runner {

    SpecificResult actOn(Entity entity, Context context) {
           return context.add(entity).specificResult();
    }
}
```

I want to see that the actOn method simply adds the entity to the context and returns the specificResult. The way I'm testing this right now is the following (using Mockito)

```
@Test
public void testActOn() {
    Entity entity = mock(Entity.class);
    Context context = mock(Context.class);
    Result result = mock(Result.class);
    SpecificResult specificResult = mock(SpecificResult.class);
    when(context.add(entity)).thenReturn(result);
    when(result.specificResult()).thenReturn(specificResult);
    Assert.assertTrue(new Runner().actOn(entity,context) == specificResult);
}
```

However this seems horribly white box, with mocks returning mocks. What am I doing wrong, and does anybody have a good "best practices" text they can point me to?

Since people requested more context, the original problem is an abstraction of a DFS, in which the Context collects the graph elements and calculates results, which are collated and returned. The actOn is actually the action at the leaves.

Comment: It's white box because you *want to see that the actOn method simply adds the entity to the context and returns the specificResult*. So, you effectively want to have a white box test. It's not wrong per se, and it does what you want.

Comment: Does the unit being tested know it's returning a mock? If not, I'd argue this isn't white-box. It's just a consequence of a unit test being very fine-grained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends of what and how much you want your code to be tested. As you mentionned the [tdd](/questions/tagged/tdd) tag, I suppose you wrote your test contracts **before** any actual production code.

So in your contract what do you want to test on the `actOn` method:

- That it returns a `SpecificResult` given both a `Context` and an `Entity`
- That `add()`, `specificResult()` interactions happen on respectively the `Context` and the `Entity`
- That the `SpecificResult` is the same instance returned by the `Result`
- etc.

Depending on what you want to be tested you will write the corresponding tests. You might want to consider relaxing your testing approach **if** this section of code **is not** critical. And the opposite if this section can trigger the end of the world as we know it.

Generally speaking whitebox tests are **brittle**, **usually verbose and not expressive**, and **difficult to refactor**. But they are well suited for critical sections that are not supposed to change a lot and by neophytes.

In your case having a mock that returns a mock **does look like** a whitebox test. But then again if you want to ensure this behavior in the production code this is ok.
Mockito can help you with deep stubs.

```
Context context = mock(Context.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
given(context.add(any(Entity.class)).specificResult()).willReturn(someSpecificResult);
```

But don't get used to it as it is usually considered bad practice and a test smell.

Other remarks :

- Your test method name is not precise enough `testActOn` does tell the reader what behavior your are testing. Usually [tdd](/questions/tagged/tdd) practitioners replace the name of the method by a contract sentence like `returns_a_SpecificResult_given_both_a_Context_and_an_Entity` which is clearly more readable and give the practitioner the scope of what is being tested.
- You are creating mock instances in the test with `Mockito.mock()` syntax, if you have several tests like that I would recommend you to use a `MockitoJUnitRunner` with the `@Mock` annotations, this will unclutter a bit your code, and allow the reader to better see what's going on in this particular test.
- Use the BDD (Behavior Driven Dev) or the AAA (Arrange Act Assert) approach.

For example:

```
@Test public void invoke_add_then_specificResult_on_call_actOn() {
    // given
    ... prepare the stubs, the object values here

    // when
    ... call your production code

    // then
    ... assertions and verifications there
}
```

All in all, as Eric Evans told me **Context is king**, you shall take decisions with this context in mind. But you really should stick to best practice as much as possible.

There's many reading on test here and there, [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDrivenDevelopment.html) has very good articles on this matter, James Carr compiled a list of [test anti-patterns](http://blog.james-carr.org/2006/11/03/tdd-anti-patterns/), there's also many reading on using well the mocks (for example the [don't mock types you don't own](https://www.google.com/search?q=don%27t%20mock%20type%20you%20don%27t%20own) mojo), Nat Pryce is the co-author of [Growing Object Oriented Software Guided by Tests](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/) which is in my opinion a must read, plus you have google ;)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using *fakes* instead of *mocks*. It's not really clear what the classes in question are meant to to, but if you can build a simple in-memory (not thread-safe, not persistent etc) implementation of both interfaces, you can use that for flexible testing without the brittleness that sometimes comes from mocking.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use names beginning `mock` for all my mock objects.  Also, I would replace

```
 when(result.specificResult()).thenReturn(specificResult); 
 Assert.assertTrue(new Runner().actOn(entity,context) == specificResult);
```

with

```
Runner toTest = new Runner();
toTest.actOn( mockEntity, mockContext );
verify( mockResult ).specificResult();
```

because all you're trying to assert is that `specificResult()` gets run on the right mock object.  Whereas your original assert doesn't make it quite so clear what is being asserted.  So you don't actually need a mock for `SpecificResult`.  That cuts you down to just one `when` call, which seems to me to be about right for this kind of test.

But yes, this does seem frightfully white box.  Is `Runner` a public class, or some hidden implementation detail of a higher level process?  If it's the latter, then you probably want to write tests around the behaviour at the higher level; rather than probing implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing much about the context of the code, I would suggest that `Context` and `Result` are likely simple data objects with very little behavior. You could use a Fake as suggested in another answer or, if you have access to the implementations of those interfaces and construction is simple, I'd just use the real objects in lieu of Fakes or Mocks.

Answer (score 0):

Although the context would provide more information, I don't see any problems with your testing methodology myself.  The whole point of mock objects is to verify calling behavior without having to instantiate the implementations.  Creating stub objects or using actual implementing classes just seems unnecessary to me.

> However this seems horribly white box, with mocks returning mocks.

This may be more about the class design than the testing.  If that is the way the `Runner` class works with the external interfaces then I don't see any problem with having the test simulate that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

First off, since nobody's mentioned it, Mockito supports chaining so you can just do:

```
when(context.add(entity).specificResult()).thenReturn(specificResult);
```

(and see Brice's comment for how to do enable this; sorry I missed it out!)

Secondly, it comes with a warning saying "Don't do this except for legacy code." You're right about the mock-returning-mock being a bit strange. It's OK to do white-box mocking generally because you're really saying, "My class ought to collaborate with a helper like <this>", but in this case it's collaborating across two different classes, coupling them together.

It's not clear why the Runner needs to get the SpecificResult, as opposed to whatever other result comes out of `context.add(entity)`, so I'm going to make a guess: the `Result` contains a result with some messages or other information and you just want to know whether it's a success or failure.

That's like me saying, "Don't tell me all about my shopping order, just tell me that I made it successfully!" The Runner shouldn't *know* that you only want that specific result; it should just return everything that came out, the same way that Amazon shows you your total, postage and all the things you bought, even if you've shopped there lots and are perfectly aware of what you're getting.

If some classes regularly use your Runner just to get a specific result while others require more feedback then I'd make two methods to do it, maybe called something like `add` and `addWithFeedback`, the same way that Amazon let you do one-click shopping by a different route.

However, be pragmatic. If it's readable the way you've done it and everyone understands it, use Mockito to chain them and call it a day. You can change it later if you have need.

Comment: Your example actually misses something. **By default Mockito does not use deep stub answers.** You actually have to tell Mockito to use this answer at creation time : `Mockito.mock(Context.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)` or via the annotation `@Mock(answer = RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)`. However having a mock that returns a mock is considered most of the time a test smell, and whitebox testing. Though as said in my answer or in @Lunivore's answer this might be ok under some circumstances. But avoid this testing style !

Comment: Oops, you're right! Edited to point to your comment. And an upvote for you too.